# One submit button is calling "onSubmit" for multiple unrelated forms on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I have a page with two forms. One main form and another which can be popped up in a modal, completely isolated from the main form in the DOM. They are not siblings or ancestors or anything. Both forms have an `onSubmit` function and their own button with `type=submit`. When I click the submit button in the modal form, it is also calling the `onsubmit` function for the main form. I can't figure out how to prevent this from occurring.

The DOM looks (very roughly) like this:

```
<body>
<div id="app-root">
    <...>
        <form onsubmit="submitMainForm">
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
    </...>
</div>
<div id="modal-root">
    <...>
        <form onsubmit="submitModal">
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
    </...>
</div>
</body>
```

The forms are *not* overlapping* (in the DOM, see below re. React) and the buttons *are* in their respective forms.

Both submit functions are in the general form:

```
e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    doRelevantSubmitActions();
}
```

Based on some other similar SO questions, I've also tried giving the buttons different `name` values or returning false from the `onSubmit` functions but nothing seems to prevent the one button from calling both functions.

I'd prefer to maintain the `type=submit` pattern as opposed to just using `onclick` functions as it comes with other QOL functionality (like submitting a form via the enter key)

*My only sliver of an idea is it could be a React issue? The modal form IS a child of the main form in the React tree, but it uses a Portal to the `modal-root` div to keep them separated in the actual DOM. I don't think the React component is related to this problem but I felt it was an important disclosure.

Comment: The actual code is JSX, it's really `onSubmit={e => {...}}`, so that's not the issue, both handlers are being called after all. Also, `event.returnValue` is deprecated in favor of `preventDefault()`. Returning false explicitly had no effect though.